Java 17 application doesn't work since 1 November in app engine standard environment
It seems that, since 1 November 2024, the configuration param <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled> for the appengine-web.xml is not working.
After no change in the configuration or in the cookies management, the application lost the session and is not working.
Is there a way to configure this in another way to make it work?
It is a java 17 application with maven, running in app engine standard environment with primefaces framework for the frontend.
